# Find and calculate matches in the string and array using iterators

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterator

I needed to count the number of matching words in a variable with array elements.
I used loop and iterative methods. My question is how can I simplify and improve my code?

Task sounds like:
There is an array of words called overusedWords. These are words overused in this story. You want to let the user of your program know how many times they have used these overused words.

```
let story = 'Last weekend, I took literally the most beautiful bike ride of my life. The route is called "The 9W to Nyack" and it actually stretches all the way from Riverside Park in Manhattan to South Nyack, New Jersey. It\'s really an adventure from beginning to end! It is a 48 mile loop and it basically took me an entire day. I stopped at Riverbank State Park to take some extremely artsy photos. It was a short stop, though, because I had a really long way left to go. After a quick photo op at the very popular Little Red Lighthouse, I began my trek across the George Washington Bridge into New Jersey.  The GW is actually very long - 4,760 feet! I was already very tired by the time I got to the other side.  An hour later, I reached Greenbrook Nature Sanctuary, an extremely beautiful park along the coast of the Hudson.  Something that was very surprising to me was that near the end of the route you actually cross back into New York! At this point, you are very close to the end.';

let overusedWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically'];

const storyWords = story.split(' ');

for (i = 0; i < overusedWords.length; i++){ 
    const overuseElements = betterWords.filter(overuseElementsInBetterWords = overusedWords.slice(i, i+1).includes(overuseElementsInBetterWords)); 
    console.log(overuseElements[i]+': '+overuseElements.length);
}

// really: 2
// very: 5
// undefined: 1
```

Comment: Depends on what you mean by improve? Is it efficiency you are looking for, or just a one liner code?

Comment: I mean more laconic code. One liner code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution can be to `map` through each overused word and `filter` them from the string like so:

```
let story = 'Last weekend, I took literally the most beautiful bike ride of my life. The route is called "The 9W to Nyack" and it actually stretches all the way from Riverside Park in Manhattan to South Nyack, New Jersey. It\'s really an adventure from beginning to end! It is a 48 mile loop and it basically took me an entire day. I stopped at Riverbank State Park to take some extremely artsy photos. It was a short stop, though, because I had a really long way left to go. After a quick photo op at the very popular Little Red Lighthouse, I began my trek across the George Washington Bridge into New Jersey.  The GW is actually very long - 4,760 feet! I was already very tired by the time I got to the other side.  An hour later, I reached Greenbrook Nature Sanctuary, an extremely beautiful park along the coast of the Hudson.  Something that was very surprising to me was that near the end of the route you actually cross back into New York! At this point, you are very close to the end.';

let overusedWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically'];

const storyWords = story.split(' ');

const result = overusedWords.map(word=>{
    return {
        word,
        count:storyWords.filter(sWord=>sWord==word).length
    }
});
```

Although I'm not sure how efficient it would be.